# Oclif dynamic autocomplete with http call

Tags: node.js, typescript, command-line-interface, oclif

Does Oclif support making a call to an API and getting the values returned in order to be used for autocomplete? I have the following use case:

- Multiple users are stored in a database
- When the user presses `show users <Tab> <Tab>`, the CLI should make a call to an API that returns all available users.
- The CLI should use the values returned from the API.
- The user can then select a user name, for example `show users user0001`.

Is this possible in Oclif?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'It is not possible in Oclif, however the Heroku CLI does this. Check out https://github.com/heroku/cli/tree/master/packages/autocomplete for more information.'

This is the answer from Oclif team regarding this issue. https://github.com/oclif/oclif/issues/332